# REDCap: Concat two fields and diplay in the third field if the third field is NULL in REDCap

Tags: redcap

Is created the following logic using Action Tags in REDCap:

@IF([biosample_name]='NaN ', (@SETVALUE='[biosample_id] [type]'),'[biosample_name]')

Here I have three fields [biosmaple_name], [biopsample_id], [type] (type is a dropdown list). I want the [biosmaple_name] field to be populated by concat of [biosmaple_id] and [type] if the [biosmaple_name] is empty.

When I try to enter data, I see a stray space in the [biosample_name] field and I have to remove the stary space in order for logic to work.

Anny ideas?This exact logic was working before, however, I was doing some testing so changed few field names, but then copied the original logic back, but it stopped working and started give stray space.

I have tried using 'NULL' '' in place of 'NaN'.

Thanks for your help.

@IF([biosample_name]='NaN ', (@SETVALUE='[biosample_id] [type]'),'[biosample_name]')

Answer (score 0):

To test if a field is empty, use `= ""`.

You might also try the @CALCTEXT action tag with an `if()` function, which might work more reliably than the `@IF` action tag.

Try:

```
@CALCTEXT(
  if(
    [biosample_name]="",
    concat_ws(' ',[biosample_id],[type]),
    [biosample_name]
  )
)
```

`concat_ws()` (concat with separator) was introduced in version 13.9.0 in August 2023, so if you're not on this version yet, you can pass in the space separator into the regular `concat()` function:

```
@CALCTEXT(
  if(
    [biosample_name]="",
    concat([biosample_id],' ',[type]),
    [biosample_name]
  )
)
```

In effect, this will prevent overwrite of the `biosample_name` field if it already has a value, but generate it if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the above code; however there are two issues: 1) code is converting the [type] which is a list into number, so the output is something like 1234 5 instead of 1234 Blood........ 2) [biosample_name] field in greyed out due to use of @CALCTEXT, I would like this field to be editable by the users.

Comment: If type is an enumerated field (radio, dropdown, etc) then unfortunately CALCTEXT may only operate on its raw value and not its label. So that may not be the solution for you. Also, given you need users to be able to edit the biosample_name field, CALCTEXT is also not the solution. I will add another answer to continue the SETVALUE theme and correct your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like users to be able to edit the prepopulated `[biosample_name]` field, and since `[type]` is an enum, `@CALCTEXT` won't do what you need.

So back to your earlier method using `@SETVALUE`, I see a couple of syntax issues in your original attempt. The `NULL` value already mentioned is one. Use `=""` instead.

Second, both the second and third arguments of `@IF()` must be full action tags. As it stands your second argument looks fine, maybe apart from the parentheses, which I'm not sure about regarding syntax, but your thirds argument should be modified to include `@SETVALUE`

So putting this all together, you can try this:

```
@IF([biosample_name]='', 
    @SETVALUE='[biosample_id] [type]',
    @SETVALUE='[biosample_name]'
)
```

For this to work, `[biosample_id]` and `[type]` must already be populated for their values to be used by `@SETVALUE`, and to be computed by `@IF()`. This means either puttinng `[biosample_name]` on a separate instrument, or else entering data for the former two and saving the form, and upon reload the `[biosample_name]` field should have its value prepopulated.

And when testing this, I was able to reproduce your issue with the errant space stopping the `@SETVALUE` from working.

Here I am filling it in for a new record the first time with `[biosample_name]` living on the same instrument as the others:
[image]

You can't see it there, but the biosample_name field has a prepopulated space. The red bar indicates that the field has a value that is different from what is stored in the database for this record (a new value).

And when I hit Save & Stay, the `[biosample_name]` field gets that space committed to the database:

[image]

It gets prepopulated the first time you open the form because the `@IF()` evaluates to `true`, and so the `@SETVALUE` executes and populates the field with `[biosample_id] [type]`, both of which are empty, so the space in the middle is what is inserted.

This means that when the page is saved, the next time it is opened it fails the logical check to see whether it's empty, and so the `@SETVALUE` in the False parameter fires to populate the field with its current value.

How to fix it? Use the `trim()` function in the `IF()` action tag to make sure it is true if the `[biosample_name]` field is either empty or just a space.

```
@IF(trim([biosample_name])='', 
    @SETVALUE='[biosample_id] [type]',
    @SETVALUE='[biosample_name]'
)
```

You could also separate the inputs and outputs. Move `[biosample_name]` to a subsequent instrument, **but** if someone opens that instrument too soon then you'll run into the same problem. So you should anticipate this and use `trim()` anyway. Separating it into a different instrument will only reliably work if you can ensure that data will always be entered in the right order.